# Show that $z^2=2i$ iff $z=\pm(1+i)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am reading Beardon's *Algebra and Geometry*.

> Show that $z^2=2i$ iff $z=\pm(1+i)$.

For the problem in question, first I made the multiplication $(1+i)\times(1+i)$ which showed the result but I guess it lacked generality then I proceded by trying to find all the $x$'s and $y$'s with the following procedure, (although I'm not really sure it will solve my problem): multiplying $(x+iy)\times (x+iy)$ which yielded $x^2+2xiy-y^2=2i$. My guess is that solving for $x$ and $y$ is going to prove that but I don't know how to proceed from here, solving for $y$ yielded:

$y\to i (x-(1+i))$

$y\to i (x+(1+i))$

And solving for $x$ yielded:

$x\to -i (y-(1-i))$

$x\to -i (y+(1-i))$

From here, what should I do to show that $z^2=2i$ iff $z=\pm(1+i)$? (assuming my reasoning is valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, your first solution of simply checking that $(\pm(1 + i))^2 = 2i$ *does* work, provided that you can show the following lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $p$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients of degree $n\geq 0$. Then $p$ has at most $n$ roots in $\Bbb C$. (With the convention that the degree of the zero polynomial is defined to be $-\infty$ or is left undefined.)

In fact, $p$ has *exactly* $n$ roots in $\Bbb C$ - the fundamental theorem of algebra tells us this. However, this weaker claim is enough to show that you have found all the solutions: take your polynomial to be $p(z) = z^2 - 2i$. Then you have shown $p(\pm(1 + i)) = 0$, and since $1 + i\neq -1 - i$ and $p$ cannot have more than $2$ roots, these must indeed be *all* the solutions of your original equation.

If you want to prove the lemma and need a hint, try using mathematical induction on the degree of $p$.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 3):

From $z^2 =x^2 +2ixy-y^2 =2i$.
As $x,y$ are real numbers we must have $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ and $2xy = 2$. The latter reduces to $y = 1/x$ substituting this produces $x^2 -x^{-2}=0$ which has solutions of $x = \pm1$ thus $y=\pm1$ and $z = \pm(1+i)$

Answer (score 0):

Use Euler form of representation right $$z=\left(2e^{i\pi/2}\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$$
Hence your answer. Read [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Kartikey.  It would be helpful in the future to give more detailed explanation and to typeset your formulas.

Comment: For much better explanation you can read the book higher algebra from hall and knight, there is a topic on complex numbers they have shown how to square root a complex using simple algebra in general